# Force table inside a table to fill remaining screen height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table inside a table.  I want the inside table to fill the remaining space down to the bottom of the screen.  If there are too many rows in the table to all fit on the screen, I want the table to have a vertical scrollbar.  The overall page should not have a vertical scrollbar.

I am able to add ids or classes to the elements, but the general HTML needs to stay the same if at all possible.

https://jsfiddle.net/4rv9htau/2/

A while ago I used height 100% and a fixed pixel value to account for extra height from other elements, but I want to avoid that so that I don't have to worry about changing it should the size of other elements change in the future.

```css
html,
body,
table,
tbody,
tr {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.MainCell {
  display: block;
}

table div:last-child {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: red;
}

table {
  background-color: blue;
}

table td div:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}

table td div:last-child,
table table {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="MainCell">
        <div>
          <input type="submit" name="btnBack" value="Back" id="btnBack">
          <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="Delete" id="btnDelete">
          <input type="submit" name="btnCut" value="Cut" id="btnCut">
        </div>
        <div>
          <table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>COL #1</th>
                <th>COL #2</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the usage of `vh`.

```
<td>
  <div>...</div><!-- First div -->
  <div>...</div><!-- Second div -->
</td>
```

1. Set a fixed height for the first div.
2. The height of the second div: `calc(100vh - fixed height)`.

```css
html,
body,
table,
tbody,
tr {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: red;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.MainCell {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

.MainCell>div:first-child {
  /* Center the inputs inside the div horizontally and vertically with */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.MainCell>div:nth-child(2) {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 30px);
}

table div:last-child {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  //background-color: blue;
}

table td div:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}

table td div:last-child,
table table {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="MainCell">
        <div>
          <input type="submit" name="btnBack" value="Back" id="btnBack">
          <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="Delete" id="btnDelete">
          <input type="submit" name="btnCut" value="Cut" id="btnCut">
        </div>
        <div>
          <table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>COL #1</th>
                <th>COL #2</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
                <td>Some val #1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
                <td>Some val #2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
                <td>Some val #3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
                <td>Some val #4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
                <td>Some val #5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
                <td>Some val #6</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
                <td>Some val #7</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
                <td>Some val #8</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
                <td>Some val #9</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
                <td>Some val #10</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit**

Set `.MainCell { padding: 0 }` and `table { border-collapse: collapse}` to prevent the vertical scrollbar on the overall page.

Comment: There's still a scrollbar on the page. I don't see from what though.

Comment: @dgrogan Thank you very much for the hint. The answer is edited. The `<td></td>` needs `padding: 0` and the table needs `border-collapse: collapse`.